# is there an easier way to make something like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

like the Q

i have this code

```
K1player1D.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"K1scoredLabel1"];
K1player1L.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"K1scorelLabel1"];
K1player1K.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"K1scorekLabel1"];
K1player1Q.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"K1scoreqLabel1"];
K1player1T.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"K1scoretLabel1"];
```

in viewDidLoad, for four players, so its 16 labels. is there any shorter way/code to do it ?

Comment: Did you mean for all your labels to use the same K1scoredLabel1 value, or was that a typo?

Comment: no the above labels is for player 1, i do have more for three other players , so it would be for the second player K1player2D, K1player2L ..... and so one for all the rest, and sort it would be 20 label not 16, coz its 5 labels for each player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NSMutableArray` fill all the `UILabel` inside it and in a loop:

```
int i=1;
for(Player in ArrayOfUILabel){
    Player.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:(@"K1scoredLabel%d",i)];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: how to make the array for all players ? it have to be K1player1D,K1player1L, ..... and so on until K1player2D, K1player2L, ....... ,

Comment: you could make array of array... in parent array you have just K1Player and in child K1Player1D,K1Player1L.....

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I would place them in an NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary * playerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     K1player1D,@"K1scoredLabel1",
                                     K1player1L,@"K1scorelLabel1",
                                     K1player1K,@"K1scorekLabel1",
                                     K1player1Q,@"K1scoreqLabel1",
                                     K1player1T,@"K1scoretLabel1",nil];

for(NSString * key in [playerDict allKeys]){
    PlayerObject * player = [playerDict objectForKey:key];
    player.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: this would fill the label.text only i guess ,, i have a specified labels to fill

Comment: The label.text is in a for loop and is referencing each of you player objects. I just assumed that they were labels.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this using Joels's answer combined with KVC (Key value coding). I don't know if it's a particularly good approach, but I've included it for the sake of completeness:

```
NSDictionary * playerDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"K1player1D",@"K1scoredLabel1",
                                 @"K1player1L",@"K1scorelLabel1",
                                 @"K1player1K",@"K1scorekLabel1",
                                 @"K1player1Q",@"K1scoreqLabel1",
                                 @"K1player1T",@"K1scoretLabel1",nil];

for(NSString * key in [playerDict allKeys]){
    NSString *labelName = [playerDict objectForKey:key];
    UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:labelName]; // grab the correct label using KVC
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
}
```

This could be made simpler if the label names matched the keys in the NSUserDefaults (then you could just use an array of names instead of a dictionary).